# How to set system properties using Netbeans 7.2 and Maven?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, junit, system-properties

I'm running a unit test in NetBeans 7.2. using Maven.

How to set a system property?

I've tried adding the property using:

Project Properties > Run > JVM arguments

but it doesn't make a difference. I think it may have something to do with JUnit running in a different JVM or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the NetBeans integrates to the Maven quite well, It will use the maven configuration (POM) for handling the lifecycle, e.g. clean, build(install) and test. For example, when you *right click at the project* and select "*Clean and Build*", you may see the something like the following:

```
cd D:\temp\prj\netbeans\dummy; 
JAVA_HOME=C:\\Java.Application\\Sun\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_31 "\"
C:\\Java.Application\\Sun\\NetBeans 7.1\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\"" 
clean install
```

I'm using the [maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/) for setting/passing the system properties as the following:-

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>DEF</name>
                        <value>456</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
                <argLine>-DABC=123</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

You may see that there are 2 positions for passing the system properties as the following:

1. The **systemProperties** tag
2. The **argLine** tag

Regarding to the ***argLine tag***, you can pass, not only the system properties, but also any further JVM arguments, e.g. -Xms, -Xmx as well.

You may see further information about the system properties [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html) and the argLine [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#argLine).

Comment: Netbeans 7.3 does not yet support the new systemPropertyVariables tag though.